# Rails Twitter Gem 404 Error Handling in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I have this line in my view file:

`- tweets = Twitter.user_timeline(@organization.twitter_name)`

The attr `twitter_name` is entered by the user.  If they enter an invalid twitter account name, it throws a 404 error.

How can I deal with the error to avoid getting this action controller exception? `Twitter::NotFound in Organizations#show`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ca use `rescue` to catch an exception and show a user friendly error message